# Does NEXUS LIFECYCLE support ruby gems

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I would like to know if we will be able to do security vulnerability, license and copyright scan using with `sonatype nexus lifecycle` for `ruby gems`?

I was not able to tun a trial version of IQ server due to licence requirements and see for myself. The free Application Health Check (AHC) seems to support only java based programs.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IQ Server 1.35](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXIQ/2017+Release+Notes#id-2017ReleaseNotes-1.35(August)) introduced Lifecycle XC which has very basic support for RubyGems (and other formats that are not support by Sonatype yet), but that won't provide what you're looking for.

Recently announced [IQ Server 1.46](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXIQ/Release+Notes) enabled RubyGems support in Nexus Firewall. This **might** be good enough for what you're looking for.

However if you need RubyGems support in Nexus Lifecycle, then you have to wait for that.